# Content-Digest vs Repr-Digest HTTP fields (HTTP content vs representation)

Tags: http, http-headers

In the latest draft [Digest Fields](https://httpwg.org/http-extensions/draft-ietf-httpbis-digest-headers.html) (related to it is [HTTP Message Signatures](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-message-signatures)) the authors define new HTTP fields - `Content-Digest` and `Repr-Digest` - that can be used for the purposes of integrity digests.

According to the document:

> The Content-Digest field can be used for the integrity of HTTP message content. The Repr-Digest field can be used for the integrity of HTTP representations.

I am trying to understand the difference in use-cases between these two HTTP fields.

I'm having difficulty understanding the difference between **HTTP message content** and **HTTP message representation**. There seems to be some overlap between the two. Could someone help clarify please?

Further in the document these two HTTP fields are described as follows.

> The `Content-Digest` HTTP field can be used in requests and responses to communicate digests that are calculated using a hashing algorithm applied to the actual message content.

> The `Repr-Digest` HTTP field can be used in requests and responses to communicate digests that are calculated using a hashing algorithm applied to the entire selected representation data.

Answer (score 0):

What lures some light on the difference between the two terms is the Appendix B  Examples of Unsolicited Digest from https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-httpbis-digest-headers/ . In the Appendix B you'll find examples of both headers, Content-Digest and Repr-Digest for different scenarios. The way I understood it is that the Content-Digest provides a hash only for a given part of HTTP response, whereas the Repr-Digest provides a hash for a complete content. You'll see the difference in the Range HTTP requests - the Repr-Digest field in the response will be calculated for a whole content even thou only the requested range will be returned to a client. Whereas the Content-Digest will be calculated on the partial range of the whole content.

Another example would be a response with no content (HTTP 204): a Content-Digest will be calculated on the empty message, whereas the Repr-Digest will be calculated on the content that was created.

It is also a valid case when both fields carry the same value. It's a common case when the content is returned in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

The draft standard you quoted uses the term HTTP representation, not HTTP *message* representation.

Therefore, we are talking about the [representations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#name-representations) defined by the RFC 9110 standard and this is the specific form (e.g. format, encoding, language) in which the entire resource is provided by the server.